# JPA assign data between entities with no straight relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application user has many fields, so I decided to separate it by one-to-one entities. Here's an example:

[image: diagram 1]

But then I realized that sometimes I need to get data from entities that don't have relations. For example, sometimes I have to load `BankCustomer` with `Worker` (all relations are lazy) but I don't need `Person`. With the model shown in the diagram, I have to load `BankCustomer`, then left join fetch `Person`, then left join fetch `Worker`. So I had the idea:

[image: diagram 2]

Now all entities have relations with others. I also get that one-to-one relations have a shared primary key. So there is no need for another foreign key creation for every relation.
With such model it will also be available to create a network with all types of relations so that this:
[image: diagram 3]
will become this:
[image: diagram 4]
So if I need to get `Authorities` from `Restriction`, I will not have to fetch `User` and `UserInfo` that I don't even need.
So here's my questions:

1. Is it possible to implement (with Hibernate as provider)?
2. Is it a good idea?
3. How do you deal with this kind of design issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to point **1**:

why not, as Hibernate and JPA helps implementing everithing you have in a RDBMS it should be feasable.

Just try it.

Answer to point **2**:

Not sure about this, it depends on many factors.

The Person, BankCustomer and Worker is solved with an inheritance relation determined by type.

Just have a look at [Inheritance mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html).

Have too many relations could drive you to an hell in the coding part, when you try to create or update an entity on db session.

If you need few infos, you don't necessary need a relation on the db, rather you could just write a specific *[HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)* to do that.

Answer to point **3**:

it really depends on your specific case.

Not just the model, but the amount of data you have, the kind of work on it, for example if you write once and read many, or if you write often.

And many other things.

You should provide a more specific case to have an answer here.